# How to convert a list of phrases into list of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to convert a list which contains both phrases and words to a list which contains only words. For example, if the input is:

```py
list_of_phrases_and_words = ['I am', 'John', 'michael and', 'I am', '16', 
    'years', 'old']
```

The expected output is:

```py
list_of_words = ['I', 'am', 'John', 'michael', 'and', 'I', 'am', '16', 'years', 'old']
```

What is the efficient way to achieve this is in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
list_of_words = [
    word
    for phrase in list_of_phrases_and_words
    for word in phrase.split()
]
```

An alternative that might be slightly less efficient for larger lists would be to first create a large string containing everything and then splitting it:

```
list_of_words = " ".join(list_of_phrases_and_words).split()
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is a nested for loop, whereby you split on the space character " ".

```py
words = [word for phrase in list_of_phrases_and_words for word in phrase.split(" ")]
```

Comment: FYI, space - `" "` - is the default for `split`

Comment: Thank you, but here I think explicit is better than implicit. It's quicker for a new-to-python programmer to see that is the action of split if you use it explicitly.

Comment: no probs, completely agree. Just thought it's worth mentioning :)